# Columns Equal in R

Tags: r, na, rowsum

How do I determine if columns values are equal?

Sample dataframe:

```
 A    B     C     D      E
ab   NA    NA    NA     NA
ed   dd    NA    NA     NA
ll   NA    NA    NA     NA
dd   NA    NA    ef     NA
```

How do I determine from columns 2:5 if they all contain NA?

I want my final dataframe to look like this:

```
 A    B     C     D      E       F
ab   NA    NA    NA     NA    TRUE
ed   dd    NA    NA     NA   FALSE
ll   NA    NA    NA     NA    TRUE
dd   NA    NA    ef     NA   FALSE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` and `is.na` like so:

```
df1 = read.table(text=" A    B     C     D      E
ab   NA    NA    NA     NA
ed   dd    NA    NA     NA
ll   NA    NA    NA     NA
dd   NA    NA    ef     NA
", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F)

df1$F <- rowSums(!is.na(df1[,2:5]))==0

df1

   A    B  C    D  E     F
1 ab <NA> NA <NA> NA  TRUE
2 ed   dd NA <NA> NA FALSE
3 ll <NA> NA <NA> NA  TRUE
4 dd <NA> NA   ef NA FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

It’s a bit complicated because your elements *aren’t* actually equal: they are `NA`, so we don’t know what their value is. In R (and most/all other programming languages), `NA` ≠ `NA`.

So we need to test separately whether (a) the values are all `NA` or (b) not all `NA` and (c) all equal. This becomes convoluted in R, and there are neat, if indirect, shortcuts in R. Frank’s comment mentions one of them:

```
all_equal = function (x) {
    length(unique(x)) == 1L
}
```

And now we can apply this function to your columns 2 : 5 and assign it to a new column, `F`:

```
df$F = apply(df[, 2 : 5], 1, all_equal)
```

Comment: `all.equal` takes two arguments and will error one one. I guess you're going for `function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1L`. (As far as `unique` is concerned `NA` is the same as another `NA`, which is arguably not correct, as you say.)

Comment: @Frank Correct, I always make this mistake because it’s so non-obvious that R has no operation for this. I also don’t like the `unique` hack, it strikes me as incredibly indirect. But the most direct alternative would be something along the lines of `head = xs[1]; Reduce(function (x) x == head, xs[-1])`, or maybe `all(xs[-1] == xs[1])`. Hmpf. So `unique` it is.

Answer (score 2):

Or this one maybe:

```
df$F <- apply(is.na(df)[,-1], 1, all)
```

OR (if all values in a row are `TRUE`, the `mean` value is 1)

```
df$F <- rowMeans(is.na(df)[,-1])==1
```

OR (if all values in a row are equal, the variance is 0)

```
df$F <- apply(is.na(df)[,-1], 1, var)==0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
## simulating a data frane

set.seet(1984)

df <- data.frame( A = sample(c(1,NA), 10,c(.1,.9), replace = T) , 
                  B = sample(c(1,NA), 10,c(.2,.8), replace = T), 
                  C = sample(c(1,NA), 10,c(.3,.7), replace = T), 
                  D = sample(c(1,NA), 10,c(.4,.6), replace = T),
                  E = rep(NA,10))

df

A  B  C  D  E
1  NA NA  1 NA NA
2  NA NA NA  1 NA
3   1 NA NA  1 NA
4  NA NA NA NA NA
5  NA NA NA NA NA
6  NA NA NA NA NA
7  NA NA NA  1 NA
8  NA NA NA  1 NA
9  NA NA NA NA NA
10 NA NA NA  1 NA

## count the NULL's for each column

sapply(df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

A  B  C  D  E 
9 10  9  5 10 

## count the NULL's in each  row 

apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

[1] 4 4 3 5 5 5 4 4 5 4
```